# Case sensitive branch names on Git

Tags: git, version-control, branch, rename

I have branches called:

```
Stuff/myfirstbranch
Stuff/mysecondbranch
```

And I have another branches called:

```
stuff/mythirdbranch
stuff/myfourthbranch
```

Note the case of "s".

I would like to rename the capital S to s. How do I go about doing this and pushing the changes out to my git server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you're in sync with your remote. Then:

```
# rename branch locally:
git branch -m Stuff/myfirstbranch stuff/myfirstbranch

# push new branch to remote:
git push origin stuff/myfirstbranch

# delete old branch on the remote:
git push origin :Stuff/myfirstbranch
```

Comment: When I try to run git branch -m it says "fatal: A branch named stuff/myfirstbranch already exsists"

Comment: Try renaming it to something temporary first, then renaming that temporary branch to stuff/myfirstbranch.

Comment: That works but the push gives a "stuff/myfirstbranch cannot be reolved to branch"